# Reactive dashboard in R. Problem with the ggplot (won't show the data)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

**Task**: I need to create a reactive dashboard by using ShinyApp with a given dataset. I need to create 3 inputs and at least 1 ggplot as a output.

**Dataset**: It has 14 columns (User.ID (shows user id), First.Stay (yes/no); columns 3:12 are names of places like Bars, Clubs, Restaurants..., Overall (rating), Rating (in verbal format, i.e., "good", "excellent", "bad")

| User.ID | First.Stay | Bars | Clubs | ... | Overall | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | No | 3.16 | 1.21 | ... | 3.57 | Very Good |
| User 2 | No | 2.15 | 4.8 | ... | 4.2 | Excellent |
| User 980 | Yes | 3.1 | 1.1 | ... | 2.3 | Bad |

(I skipped 977 users, but they are there; it is a big dataset.)

**Problem**: The app is running, it shows the axis I specified (x & y) but does not show any data. Here is the code below:

```r
rm(list=ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my_data <- read.csv("tripadvisor_reviews.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
any(is.na(my_data))

my_places <- my_data %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = 3:12, names_to= "places", values_to = "rating")
#the dataset is too wide, I was recommended to pivot it to long

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cyborg"), 
                
                h1("XX"), #header
                h2("Made by vopuidi"), #name
                p("xx"), #paragraph/text
                br(), #adds some space between the text & Layout
                
                
                #Layout
                
                sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(   
                        #Input 1: Numeric rating
                        sliderInput("numeric_rating", "Select the desired numeric rating", min = 0, max = 5, value = c(0,5), step = 0.5),
                        
                       #Input 2: checkboxes for desired places
                        checkboxGroupInput("desired_places", "Select all desired amusements", 
                                           choices = unique(places)),
                                           selected = c("Clubs")),
                       
                         #Input 3: for first-time travellers
                        checkboxInput("first_timers", "Display reviews by people with first stay", FALSE),
                        
                        
                    ),
                    mainPanel(#Output 1: the scatterplot
                        plotOutput("myscatter")
                        
                    ))



# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    #Output 1:
    output$myscatter = renderPlot({
        p = my_places %>%
            filter(rating >= input$numeric_rating[1] & Rating <= input$numeric_rating[2])%>%
            filter(places %in% input$desired_places)%>%
            ggplot(aes(x= places, y = rating , fill = Overall))+
            geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
   
        
        print(p)})
    

    }

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is what I get when I run the app. [image]

What is wrong? Did I miss some specification of data and R is looking in a wrong place?

Second problem is "Input 2" within the code used above—i.e.,

```r
#Input 2: checkboxes for desired places
 checkboxGroupInput("desired_places", "Select all desired amusements", 
                    choices = unique(places)),
                    selected = c("Clubs")),
```

It does not give the results I wanted, rather provides all columns, instead of unique entries in 1 specific column.
[image]

Comment: Remove `print(p)` from your `renderPlot`. Replace it with simply `p`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe problem 2 is causing problem 1.

What is `choices = unique(places)` doing in the checkboxInput? `places` is not defined anywhere in your snippet. You probably mean `unique(my_places$places)`, that is, the unique values of the `places` column in your `my_places` dataset.

As long as the input element isn't working correctly due to problem #2 the second `filter()` call in the server block will not have any sensible value to work with, and will never match anything in your dataset. `ggplot` gets an empty dataset as input and plots exactly that.